# afterUpdate event on clientCache region gemfire

Tags: java, caching, listener, gemfire

I have 2 java applications A and B. Application A runs on a weblogic server and B is a standalone java application. There is a gemfire cache region R on application A, that I connect to using  from B.
I need to create a listener on region R that checks the update of an entry in that region and triggers an event in application B.
Now, I have looked at the gemfire documentation for creating cache listeners on the same server, but how do I do it from a different application and trigger an event in this other application.
A solution would be to set up a queue and drop a message from A to B but, is it possible to do it using Gemfire.
So my question is, can I do something like this :

```
    <gfe:client-region id="XYZ" data-policy="EMPTY"
        pool-name="XYZCache">
       <gfe:cache-listener>
           <ref bean="ABC" />
       </gfe:cache-listener>
    </gfe:client-region>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to the keys in the region you are interested in from the client, then, put a listener on the client, similar to how you show above.

The thing you want in application B is the subscription, which you do via "register-interest".  See the docs here:

http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/events/configure_client_server_event_messaging.html